# How can I develop a 3d data visual graph?

Tags: mysql, facebook, web-services, design-patterns

What services can I use to develop a 3d graph similar to Facebook's here?

I would like to be able to use mysql data to populate the graph with data.

[image: Facebook Graph]

[image: Graph of relations]
<sub>(source: [searchenginestrategy.org](http://searchenginestrategy.org/wp-content/uploads/2010/08/social_graph.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arbor JS is a fantastic tool that is very flexible and easy to use: http://arborjs.org/